# How to check the username is valid

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

Actually i tried to check the username and password is correct in the login page.
So i written code about to login  .Checking whether the user is valid when the log out button is visible.

But my statement is not working

```
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(sUsername);
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(sPassword);
driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();


boolean logvisibile = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account']/ul/li[2]/a")).isDisplayed();


Thread.sleep(1000);

if(logvisibile == true)

{
System.out.println("Succesfull");

}else

{
System.out.println("Failed");

}
}
```

**Out put:

> FAILED: test(“testuser_1″, “Test@123″)
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   {“method”:”xpath”,”selector”:”.//*[@id=’account’]/ul/li[2]/a”} Command
>   duration or timeout: 10.06 seconds For documentation on this error,
>   please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are checking the visibility of the LogOut button even before clicking the Login. (Assuming `//*[@id='account']/ul/li[2]/a` is your logout button)

```
boolean logvisibile = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account']/ul/li[2]/a")).isDisplayed();
driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
```

First click on the login, then check visibility.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
boolean logvisibile = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account']/ul/li[2]/a")).isDisplayed();
```

Also no need to do this - `if(logvisibile == true)` you may simply do `if(logvisible)`

EDIT: Check this solution for a login scenario, works perfectly fine.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://newtours.demoaut.com/mercurysignon.php");

    WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='userName']"));
    username.sendKeys("dharam111");

    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='password']"));
    password.sendKeys("password");

    WebElement loginBtn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='login']"));
    loginBtn.click();

    List<WebElement> objLogOutLink = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href*='signoff']"));
    if(objLogOutLink.size() > 0){
        if(objLogOutLink.get(0).getText().contains("SIGN-OFF")){
            System.out.println("Login successful...Success");
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Login Failed.");
    }

}
```

Comment: THanks for helping ..

Still the error showing like "Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='account']/ul/li[2]/a"}
Command duration or timeout: 10.40 seconds...."
still if loop is not executing

**Also am entering invalid username for checking**.

Comment: Can you post the HTML snippet of your LogOut button ?

Comment: You can also try this to check visibility - `WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account']/ul/li[2]/a")));`

Comment: 'html lang="en">
<head>
<body class="theme-Progressive project-avc-dev controller-issues action-index">
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="wrapper2">
<div id="wrapper3">
<div id="top-menu">
<div id="account">
<ul>
<li>
<li>
<a class="logout"  data-method="post" href="/logout">Sign out</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="loggedas">
<ul>
</div>
<div id="header">
<div id="main" class="">
</div>'

Comment: log out button is not visible in the login page and am not entering to the home page.(beuase am uisin invalid username and password).
So always its showing "Unable to locate element.
How could i get a proper output .Also if loop is not working